# Why is Smooth Frequency Giving 2 Counts for a Single Category, Gnuplot 5.0.3 CentOS 6.7?

Tags: gnuplot, frequency, smoothing

I am encountering a problem with gnuplot 5.0.3 using the smooth frequency function. I am using the function on data that Looks like the sample row below with 4140 rows using the attached gnpulot script. 
I am using smooth frequency within the plot command, once in the set table wrapper to output the frequency data in $DB and once in the actual graph plotting command.
In both times output is produced with 2 counts for same bin or category. The column in accval_col contains discrete integer data from 1 to 9, and the required job is to count the occurences of these categories and plot them in a histogramm.

If i run the script for the first 3400 records it performs the counts correctly after that the problem occurs. The splitted counts given for each category, sum up to the total count for the category. But i have no explanation why this split is happening and how to eliminate it.

I would appreciate any help on this, thanks.

```
    reset
    reset session

    #input file
    accfile=ARG1


    #out_path=ARG2

    #columns
    accval_col=21
    misses_col=13
    #########################################################################
    set term qt #pdfcairo font "Arial,7"
    set datafile separator ";"
    #print out_path
    set output out_path
    stats accfile u (((stringcolumn(misses_col)eq "\N") || (column(misses_col)==0))?column(accval_col):1/0) name "acc" #nooutput

    set table $DB
    plot accfile  u (((stringcolumn(misses_col)eq "\N") || (column(misses_col)==0))?column(accval_col):1/0):(1.0*100/acc_records) smooth frequency  

    unset table
    print $DB


    set multiplot
    unset key
    set yrange [0:100]
    set xrange [0.5:8.5]
    set xtics ("<=3m" 1, "<=7,5m" 2, "<=12m" 3, "<=15m" 4, "<=20" 5, "<=30m" 6, "<=40m" 7, "<=50m" 8)  
    set boxwidth 0.5
    set style fill solid 0.5
    set xlabel "Kategorie"
    set ylabel "Häufigkeit in %"
    set title "Häufigkeitsdiagramm von Fehler Kategorien"
    unset grid
    set margins   8, 8, 6, 6
    plot accfile  u (((stringcolumn(misses_col)eq "\N") || (column(misses_col)==0))?column(accval_col):1/0):(1.0*100/acc_records)  smooth frequency  w boxes

    set yrange[0:100]
    unset xlabel
    unset ylabel
    unset title
    unset ytics
    unset xtics


    set datafile separator
    plot $DB u (stringcolumn(3) ne "u"?column(1):1/0):(column(2)+ 1.5):2 w labels
    unset multiplot
    set o
```

[image]

A sample line of the Input data, only relevant columns for the script is 21 (2nd from the back)

```
    2016-03-17;86347;1;26.68;300.14;;;;; ;3949600;FRA_VC_CAT10_SMR_W_032016;1;2476187;\N;2476187;-8.53550654341171;5.943441933097802;FRA_VC_CAT10_SMR_W_032016;6125718;3;10.400931398905074
```

Output on STDOUT:

```
    * FILE: 
      Records:           4138
      Out of range:         0
      Invalid:              2
      Blank:                0
      Data Blocks:          1

    * COLUMN: 
      Mean:               3.3971
      Std Dev:            1.2643
      Sample StdDev:      1.2645
      Skewness:           0.9423
      Kurtosis:           4.1839
      Avg Dev:            1.0162
      Sum:            14057.0000
      Sum Sq.:        54367.0000

      Mean Err.:          0.0197
      Std Dev Err.:       0.0139
      Skewness Err.:      0.0381
      Kurtosis Err.:      0.0762

      Minimum:            1.0000 [   6]
      Maximum:            9.0000 [4002]
      Quartile:           3.0000 
      Median:             3.0000 
      Quartile:           4.0000 


    # Curve 0 of 1, 20 points
    # Curve title: "accfile  u (((stringcolumn(misses_col)eq "\N") || (column(misses_col)==0))?column(accval_col):1/0):(1.0*100/acc_records)"
    # x y type
     1  1.08748  i
     2  21.7013  i
     3  33.0594  i
     4  13.0256  i
     5  10.5848  i
     6  2.27163  i
     7  0.652489  i
     8  0.314161  i
     9  0.338328  i
     1  0.0241663  u
     1  0.144998  i
     2  1.57081  i
     3  5.58241  i
     4  3.67327  i
     5  3.67327  i
     6  2.1508  i
     7  0.120831  i
     8  0.0241663  i
     9  0.0241663  i
     1  0.0241663  u
```

Comment: Update: the Count is always divided by the total number of records so that the displayed values are percentages.

Comment: From what I can see in your data, it looks like you might have empty lines in your original datafile. This could be either because you have the actual empty lines or because you're ignoring some of the lines (the `1/0` in your script perhaps?). gnuplot then separates the blocks of data. You can test this behavior with a fairly simple test data file with a few records separated by an empty line.

Comment: It's true i can reproduce the error by inserting blank lines in a test Input file. but using "grep -cvP '\S' inputfile.csv" in the shell to check for blank lines in my original Input file i get zero blank lines in return. So i am still puzzled why this is happening if my file has no blank lines?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment, it could be that the `1/0` is "creating" an empty line. Do the same test with a simple test data file with no empty lines where, for instance, one of the records is 1.234, then use `u 1:($2 == 1.234 ? 1/0 : $2)` to see if this reproduces the error (by skipping that particular record).